# How many times can a player spend Advantage on a specific action?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, advantage-and-disadvantage

While running the Beginner Adventure some of my players were rolling a lot of advantage symbols (but without a success) and trying to maximize the chance of success for other players  by using their advantage to give out Boost dice. During one such roll a player had six advantage and wanted to give out 3 boost dice to the same player, I made a session ruling that a player could only spend advantage in that way once per turn, but I wanted to find out what it should be for the long run of the game as we intend to continue playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using Advantages this way is a part of the system

Using the dice pool for the *FFG Star Wars roleplaying games* is a collaborative process with all the players, and assigning the narrative outcome of the results is a part of that. It is quite possible for a roll that includes numerous Advantages to be passed on in the form of Boost to the next Active character.

> The key here is that how the Advantages gained from that roll are
>   narrated into being a Boost for the subsequent player.

It is quite common for a combat to include quite a few Boost Dice (and Setback dice from Threats) being passed around from player to player and to GM with a well-described rationale from the scene as to why that would be so.

**Step 4** of the **Combat Check Process** for the system (page 205 in *Edge of the Empire*) discusses the use of the two charts (6-2, 6-3) for Spending Advantages and Triumphs, and Spending Threats and Despair. This spells out that the charts are intended as examples, and the group is expected to use those examples as benchmarks for narrating the outcomes of their rolls. The GM is expected to let the group narrate these outcomes, unless there is a specific reason pertinent to the scene (such as a detail about a location or person that they do not know and so cannot use to properly narrate a specific result). This whole process is intended to be part of the fun and is a significant aspect of what brings about the feeling of Star Wars in the game.

Having players narrating and coordinating together as players and as characters is a part of the intended process, and will allow for some spectacular scenes (for and against the group) as you play. Sometimes, those Boost dice will come up blank...

### If you really must restrict the use of Advantages...

As the GM, remembering to apply Strain appropriately, and recognizing the importance of activating Item Qualities and Criticals can help in reducing the volume of Advantages turned into Boost dice to pass on, but there are times when the group will want all the Boosts it can get.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I was running things mechanically correct. I have been using threat dice for strain and having players use advantage to remove strain it was just in this once case this player had no strain and no abilities he could activate.

Comment: That will happen. Sometimes, a chain of actions will occur that have more and more Boost being passed around the table as you go through the initiative sequence. That can make for some heroic stuff~

Answer (score 0):

I perfer to do it a bit differently, though it gets a bit easier since my players tend to prefer using their advantages for weapon abilities.

When a player wants to use a non weapon ability (for example giving allys Boost dice) I ask them to exactly explain what they are doing. If it makes sense, actualy helps and is (relativly) new, aka "rule of cool", I try to give appropriate bonuses. These bonuses usualy just consume the rest of the advantage dice, as i rarely let the players reduce strain with them (personal preferance).

Another option is to use the advantages to make the players aware of something. Though it was not in one of my adventures, or even my idea, as we were attacked by a large group of gamborians(I hope they are called that in english), eventually a character missed, but had a ton of advantages. Instead he hit the water tower, which shuddered (but did not fall). This made us reevaluate our surroundings and shoot down the watertower, letting us escape in the ensuing chaos.

This is, in my oppinion the best way to use advantages and disadvantages. Let the players shoot the pipes, drenching the enemies in hot steam, giving them disadvantage. Let them see the enemy sneeking up on their friend. Give them information about their surroundings they can use to make the fight more interesting.

Once you start doing this, your players will eventually start to realize the fun they can have with the advantage dice and start making their own explainations. Of course you sometimes need to reign them in, but if you give the enemies the same chances, you suddenly have much more dynamic fights and a whole lot of "THAT WAS AWESOME" moments.

Naturally you dont want to overdo it, so when it's just a small confrontation, just let it roll. You know the players aren't in any real danger and dont try to fudge it with some random stuff that happens to them. When the stakes are hight though, start to have some fun. Especially for the big final fight, plan the terrain, and think of the awesome stuff you could let happen. Having something in the backhand means that, in case you can't think of anything, you have something to fall back on instead of "you regain 1 strain".

Finally, remember it is not just your job to do the imagining. Let the players do their part.

Sorry for the long answer, but we had pretty much the same problem in some of the early adventures...